# SVG file not showing as background image (SASS)

Tags: html, css, svg, sass

I'm using dart sass (1.49.11) and the folder structure is this one:

```
~/web-projects/sass-test/
    |
    |--- index.html
    |--- styles.css (the output generated by "sass --watch stylesheet.scss styles.css" on the console)
    |--- styles.css.map
    |--- stylesheet.scss
    |--- colorful-abstract-background.svg
```

I have the following markup:

```
  <body>
    <main>
      <section class="hero-section">
        <div class="container">
          <h1>Life Should Be Easy</h1>
          <p>
            Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla...
          </p>
          <a class="cta-btn">Get started</a>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
  </body>
```

And this is the code in stylesheet.scss:

```
.hero-section {
  .container {
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url("colorful-abstract-background.svg");
  }
}
```

And the thing is that 'colorful-abstract-background.svg' is not showing, the console doesn't show any error and the network tab in the dev tools (Firefox) says that indeed the browser requested for the SVG file as "type: image", code 200, but again it's not showing.

Btw I'm using the live server extension in VSCode on MacOS Big sur (Idk if that helps).

What's the problem?

EDIT 1:
If I use a .png image or the linear-gradient function it works but apparently the problem just happens when I try with SVGs.

EDIT 2:
My index.html is properly linked to styles.css if you ask (I have some other styles such as color and font-family that are rendered).

Comment: What do the dev tools show what the actual response body was? Does your server deliver the SVG with an appropriate Content-Type header?

Comment: values in style rules are not quotted. try removing the "" from the url argument: `background-image: url(colorful-abstract-background.svg);`